# TikZ: Node names with a "."

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

In TikZ, for some node (x), one can use e.g. (x.west) to refer to anchors of the node x. If I try to by hand define a coordinate with a "." in the name, this doesn't work:

```
\coordinate (x.test) at (4,0);
```

Is there any way to define a coordinate such that (x.text) refers to this coordinate?

Comment: You can define your own shape in which `test` is an anchor.

Comment: Other than that I really do not think there is any reasonable possibility. You cannot have points, commas, parentheses, square brackets, dollar signs and so on in node names without causing trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can name a coordinate (or generally a node) with a `.`in its name.
But you're not going to have a good time.

Of the following solutions, I only consider the last one (using the node cs explicitly) to be a valid and stable solution.

1. is annoying.
2. can make a mess since `.` is now a letter and can be used inside macro names (there's an alternative by making `.` active which might be saver actually).
3. is just more to write but also unambiguous to others.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{no anchors/.code={\catcode`\.=11\relax}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (x.test) at (4,0);

% 1. Hide the dot from TikZ parser.
\node[shift=(up:2)] (no dot) at ({{{{x.test}}}}) {no dot};
% 2. “Disguise” the dot as a different character
\draw {[no anchors] (x.test) } -- (no dot.south);
% 3. Explicitly use the node cs.
\draw (0,4) -- (node cs: name = x.test);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want to add an extra anchor to an *existing* node you can use `append after command` or pics as [I did in another answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/659619) (though, if you can live with `x-test` use that, it's much easier).

We can also add new anchors to plain nodes as I did in [another answer with the same tactic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660086).

If you also want to use these anchors for placing a node, more work is done, but that can be solved pretty straight-forward, I believe.

But for that, I'd need to see your actual use-case.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking

> Is there any way to define a coordinate such that (x.text) refers to
>   this coordinate?

Technically, there is. You could redefine (locally I hope) the `coordinate` shape to have a `test` anchor.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{coordinate}
{
\savedanchor\centerpoint{%
\pgf@x=.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
\pgf@y=.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
\advance\pgf@y by -.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
}
\anchor{center}{\centerpoint}
\anchor{test}{\centerpoint}
\anchorborder{\centerpoint}
}
\makeatother
\coordinate (x) at (4,0);
\draw (x.test) -- ++ (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, I do not recommend at all using this or similar constructions. Rather, I'd like to argue it is much better to accept the fact that you cannot have points, commas, parentheses, square brackets, braces (that get interpreted as such), `~`, plain dollar signs, plain `#`s, plain pipes, plain `%`, ampersands and perhaps a few more do not work. (Depending on the packages you load, this list may get longer anyway.) Personally I am really amazed by the fact that e.g. spaces and underscores do work. Having these special characters makes is very convenient to deal with Ti*k*Z. If you wanted to allow `.` then there will either be ambiguities, or you would have to forbid users to use `(node.north)` to refer to the north anchor.

Comment: Thanks! What I'm actually searching for is an easy way to make custom node shapes without having to go to low-level pgf. So far I'm using TeX commands that do the drawing in TikZ, and was looking for a way to mimick node anchors. Is your example above the shortest way to define a shape without drawing, but only anchors?

Comment: @AndiBauer I copied the definition of the `coordinate` shape and added an anchor, so it might be the shortest way. But I do not yet understand the purpose of this. Why precisely do you want to have these anchors or coordinate names that contain a period?

Comment: I want to be able to place complicated shapes and connect them by lines. Defining custom node shapes seems too cumbersome though. So I use nodes with predefined shapes for the simpler shapes, and TeX commands for more complicated ones. These TeX commands automatically define coordinates with names like "node1*west". It would be nice to be able to access these fake anchors in the same way as the real node anchors.

Comment: @AndiBauer Maybe you are looking for `pic`s? They allow you to draw shapes in a very simple way, and refer to predefined coordinates from outside.

Comment: That sounds promising, will check that out!