# path picture add custom anchor

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

I would like to create an antenna shape in TikZ with custom anchors. Since I am struggling with `\pgfdeclareshape`, I am using `path picture` instead.

Is it possible to make the coordinates created inside the `path picture` command accessible as anchors?

Also, is it possible to rotate the entire shape around the center point including the defined anchors?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\tikzset{antenna/.style={draw=none,
    path picture={
        \draw coordinate (feed) at (path picture bounding box.west);
        \draw coordinate (center) at (path picture bounding box.center);
        \draw coordinate (phase center) at (path picture bounding box.east);
        \draw (feed)-- (center);
        \draw (center)-- (path picture bounding box.north east);
        \draw (center)-- (path picture bounding box.south east);
}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[antenna] (antenna1) {};
        %\draw[->] (antenna1.phase center)-- ++(1, 1);  % I want this to work
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are looking for `pic`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.

Comment: I'm voting to leave open because the comment is quite minimal - I wouldn't know how to implement this from the comment alone.

Answer (score 4):

We could name a coordinate that it is named `antenna1.phase center` but since the `.` is used by TikZ to detect a node-with-anchor specification we would need to use the explicit version, i.e. `(node cs: name=antenna.phase center)` and then it might be better to define fake anchors (i.e. coordinates as you have used them) but just with `-` instead of `.`.

### `path picture` with `-` instead of `.`

We could do this as such:

```
\documentclass[border=1pt,tikz]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{name prefix node name/.style={name prefix/.expanded=\tikz@fig@name}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  antenna/.style={
    draw=none,
    path picture={
      \tikzset{name prefix node name}
      \coordinate (-feed)   at (path picture bounding box.west)
       coordinate (-center) at (path picture bounding box.center)
       coordinate (-phase center) at (path picture bounding box.east);
      \draw (-feed)   -- (-center)
            (-center) -- (path picture bounding box.north east)
            (-center) -- (path picture bounding box.south east);}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[antenna] (antenna1) {};
\draw[->] (antenna1-phase center)-- ++(1, 1);% close enough
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here the `name prefix` is set up with the name of that node in whose `path picture` we are.

### `append after command` with added anchors for this shape

Note, however, as you defined it `antenna1.phase center` is just `antenna1.east`.

That is, unless you rotate the node but then all the `path picture bounding box` anchors aren't correct anymore either since the path picture bounding box won't rotate with. You'd want an `append after command` then since it will have the same transformation as the source node.

Let's do it that way and add our special anchors only for that node:

```
\documentclass[border=1pt,tikz]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  add anchor to node/.code n args={3}{%
    \edef\tikz@temp##1{%  \tikz@pp@name/\tikzlastnode needs to be expanded
      \noexpand\pgfutil@g@addto@macro\expandafter\noexpand\csname pgf@sh@ma@\tikz@pp@name{#1}\endcsname{%
        \def\expandafter\noexpand\csname pgf@anchor@\csname pgf@sh@ns@\tikz@pp@name{#1}\endcsname @#2\endcsname{##1}%
      }}\tikz@temp{#3}},
  add anchor alias to node/.style n args={3}{
    add anchor to node={#1}{#2}{\pgf@sh@reanchor{\csname pgf@sh@ns@\pgfreferencednodename\endcsname}{#3}}},
  add anchor alias to me/.style args={#1 for #2}{append after command={
      [add anchor alias to node={\tikzlastnode}{#1}{#2}]}}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  antenna/.style={
    draw=none, add anchor alias to me/.list={phase center for east,feed for west},
    append after command={(\tikzlastnode.center) edge (\tikzlastnode.feed)
      edge (\tikzlastnode.north east) edge (\tikzlastnode.south east)}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[antenna, rotate=10] (antenna1) {};
\draw[->] (antenna1.phase center)-- ++(1, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Pic

That said, before we re-invent the `pic`, let's use that instead.

#### `-` instead of `.`

Though, we're going to use `-` instead of `.` again. A `pic` sets the appropriate `name prefix` on its own so every `coordinate` we define gets the name of the `pic` prefixed.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt,tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  pics/antenna/.default=.3333em,
  pics/antenna/.style={code={
      \path[pic actions] (0,0) coordinate (-center) edge (left:#1) coordinate (-feed)
        edge (#1,#1) edge (#1,-#1) coordinate (-phase center) at (right:#1);}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic (antenna1) {antenna};
\draw[->] (antenna1-phase center)-- ++(1, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

That's pretty easy and we even can use a pic along a path and rotate it and change colors and …

#### *Real* pic anchors?

With a little hackery again, we can add anchors to a pic that references a coordinate inside the pic.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt,tikz]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  add anchor to node/.code n args={3}{%
    \edef\tikz@temp##1{% \tikz@pp@name/\tikzlastnode needs to be expanded
      \noexpand\pgfutil@g@addto@macro\expandafter\noexpand\csname pgf@sh@ma@\tikz@pp@name{#1}\endcsname{%
        \def\expandafter\noexpand\csname pgf@anchor@\csname pgf@sh@ns@\tikz@pp@name{#1}\endcsname @#2\endcsname{##1}%
      }}\tikz@temp{#3}},
  add anchor to pic/.style args={#1 to #2}{
    /utils/exec=\pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@\tikz@pp@name{}}{\pgfcoordinate{\tikz@pp@name{}}{\pgfpointorigin}}{},
    add anchor to node/.expanded={}{#1}{\noexpand\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@pp@name{#2}}{center}}}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  pics/antenna/.default=.3333em,
  pics/antenna/.style={code={
    \path[pic actions] (0,0) coordinate (-center) edge (left:#1) coordinate (-feed)
      edge (#1,#1) edge (#1,-#1) coordinate (-phase center) at (right:#1);
    \tikzset{
      add anchor to pic/.list={phase center to -phase center, feed to -feed}}
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic (antenna1) {antenna};
\draw[->] (antenna1.phase center)-- ++(1, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That answer is awesome… but I wanted to generalize your approach to use the pic inside a node like `\node[antennaStyle]{};` where `antenna/.style={append after command={pic {antenna}}}`… but I get error `ERROR: Missing \endcsname inserted.` when I try your code this way. The end goal would be to create new anchors with styles `antennaStyle` to the parent node directly.

Comment: For the robust version, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/676017/tikz-pic-use-internal-nodes-as-anchor-name/676090#676090 (thanks again!)