# Tikz pic: use internal nodes as anchor name

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

I'd like to use pics to easily and quickly create new node shapes. Sadly, I can't find how to use internal nodes to define anchors. For instance, I'd like the B to point to the small x in the ground symbol:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  groundpic/.pic={
    % Code for the ground
    \draw[line width=.4pt]
    (0,0) -- (1mm,0)
    -- +(0,1mm) -- +(0,-1mm)
    ++(.4mm,0)
    -- +(0,.7mm) -- +(0,-.7mm) node[anchor=center,scale=.5,name=myanchor] {x}
    ++(.4mm,0)
    -- +(0,.35mm) -- +(0,-.35mm)
    ;
  },
  ground/.style={
    shape=coordinate, % Otherwise the arrow will not point to the center
    append after command={
      pic[scale=2] {groundpic}
    },
  },
}

Goal: add an arrow to x, but end anchor=myanchor fails:
\noindent\begin{tikzcd}
  A \rar & |[ground]| & \\
  B \ar[
    ru,
    % end anchor=myanchor
  ]
\end{tikzcd}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [This seems related.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/659619) Though maybe it would be better to name the pic based on the cell, i.e. `matrixname-row-column` and name the node `-myanchor` which would be actually named `matrixname-row-column-myanchor` and use that as the `to` from the `\arrow`.  Aren't these shapes already defined by circuit libraries/packages?

Comment: Please clarify, where should be  label ground symbol?  (for example, above it?). If you like to draw electrical schemes, `tikz-cd` is not right tool, See `circuitikz` package,

Comment: @Zarko thanks, @Qrrbrbirlbel answered nicely my question. Regarding `circuitikz`, I'm actually building my own library (zx-calculus on CTAN) and circuitikz was not really meant for this kind of diagrams as I want a matrix layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A node can't be a real anchor.
An anchor is always one single point. It can't be another node.

Two things can be done, though:

- We can add an anchor to an existing node (or coordinate which is just a special node).

  For this, I adjusted [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/659619/16595) to “[path picture add custom anchor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/576909/16595)” which was problematic but didn't show in the linked answer. This should be more robust now.
- We can name a node in a pic which is actually named `<pic name><node name>` on the global scale. (TikZ sets up `name prefix = <pic name>` which means every named coordinate or node uses this prefix unless [`name prefix ..`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-pics#tikz/name:prefix:..) is given.)

  If we also name the node the same as a *matrix of (math) nodes* names its cells' nodes we can incorporate this easily into TikZ-CD (see the adjustments to the `ground` style).

---

Now, we could actually just use

```
\ar[ru, name suffix=<node name>]
```

but this would apply for both start and target and for every coordinate/node we define on the way.

And for this small example it only applies for the start not the target?

```
\begin{tikzcd}[arrows=help lines]
  |[ground]| \ar[r, bend right=90, name suffix=-east]
& |[ground]| \ar[l, bend right=90, name suffix=-east]
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

Weird. (When TikZ encounters a node coordinate specification, i.e. `(<node name>)` it first tries to find a node with both name prefix and suffix and if it doesn't find that it checks for a node without these added.)

This is why I propose the keys `from pic node` and `to pic node` (which also adds the `-` for you):

```
\begin{tikzcd}[arrows=help lines]
  |[ground]| \ar[r, bend right=90, from pic node=east, to pic node=east]
& |[ground]| \ar[l, bend right=90, from pic node=east, to pic node=east]
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

These keys should be use after the target is specified, i.e. after `ru` or the usage of `to`/`from` otherwise the setting is lost again.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  add anchor to node/.code n args={3}{%
    \edef\tikz@temp##1{% \tikz@pp@name/\tikzlastnode needs to be expanded
      \noexpand\pgfutil@g@addto@macro\expandafter\noexpand\csname
        pgf@sh@ma@\tikz@pp@name{#1}\endcsname{%
        \def\expandafter\noexpand\csname pgf@anchor@\csname
          pgf@sh@ns@\tikz@pp@name{#1}\endcsname @#2\endcsname{##1}%
      }%
    }%
    \tikz@temp{#3}%
  },
  add anchor to pic'/.style={/tikz/add anchor to pic={#1}{-#1}},
  add anchor to pic/.code 2 args={%
    % If base coordinate isn't created yet, do so at (0,0)
    % in the current coordinate system!
    \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@\tikz@pp@name{}}{%
      \pgfcoordinate{\tikz@pp@name{}}{\pgfpointorigin}%
    }{}%
    \begingroup
      % What is the distance between coordinate and base?
      % We have to do this in the coordinate system of the base coordinate.
      \pgfsettransform{\csname pgf@sh@nt@\tikz@pp@name{}\endcsname}%
      \pgf@process{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@pp@name{#2}}{center}}%
      % This distance is the new anchors coordinate
      % in the base's coordinate system.
      % Adding an anchor to a node must be global
      % which is why we can do this inside the group.
      \pgfkeysalso{
        /tikz/add anchor to node/.expanded=%
          {}{#1}{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}}
      }%
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\tikzcdset{
  from pic node/.code=\edef\tikzcd@ar@start{\tikzcd@ar@start-#1},
  to pic node/.code=\edef\tikzcd@ar@target{\tikzcd@ar@target-#1}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  groundpic/.pic={
    % Code for the ground
    \draw[line width=.4pt] (0,0) -- (1mm,0)
         +(0, 1mm) coordinate(-t1) -- +(0,-1mm) coordinate(-b1)
        ++(.4mm,0) +(0,.7mm) coordinate(-t2) -- +(0,-.7mm) coordinate(-b2)
        ++(.4mm,0) +(0,.35mm) coordinate(-t3)--  +(0,-.35mm)coordinate(-b3)
        node[scale=.4, below, rotate=90, midway, inner sep=+3pt, rectangle]
          (-east) {Ground};
%    \node[draw, help lines](){4444};
%    \coordinate(-b4) at (.west);
    \tikzset{add anchor to pic'/.list={t1, b1, t2, b2, t3, b3}}
  },
  ground/.style={
    shape=coordinate, yshift=axis_height,
    append after command={
      pic[scale=2,at=(\tikzlastnode),name=\tikzlastnode]{groundpic}
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \rar & |[ground]| \\
  B
  \foreach \num in {1,2,3}{
    \foreach\tORb/\leftORright in {t/left,b/right}{
      \expanded{\noexpand\ar[
        bend \leftORright, -, help lines, ru , end anchor=\tORb\num]}
    }
  }
  \ar[ru, out=0, in=-30, "Here's the ground"' math mode=false, name suffix=-east]
\end{tikzcd}
\begin{tikzcd}[arrows=help lines]
  |[ground]| \ar[r, bend right=90, name suffix=-east]
& |[ground]| \ar[l, bend right=90, name suffix=-east]
\end{tikzcd}
\begin{tikzcd}[arrows=help lines]
  |[ground]| \ar[r, bend right=90, from pic node=east, to pic node=east]
& |[ground]| \ar[l, bend right=90, from pic node=east, to pic node=east]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you sooo much, this last robust definition of `add anchor to pic` together with `name=\tikzlastnode` (actually, can't this cause some conflicts as now two nodes have the same name?) is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @tobiasBora No, only one node is named `\tikzmatrixname-<row>-<col>`: the coordinate you declare in the `ground` style. While the pic is syntactally named the pic isn't actually an object that has (and keeps) a name. All a named pic does is setup the the appropriate `name prefix`. The coordinate and nodes inside the pic all use that prefix and then what. If you would name a coordinate `()` it would actually named like the coordinate from `ground` but that one is just lost then (and so would any anchors we added to it).

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for the clarification!

Comment: Actually, it's even better than I would imagine: if I define a node with an empty name, it replaces the node of the matrix, therefore stuff like `\rar` will not go through the node, and will stop on its boundary :-D

Comment: Arg… actually this was a bit too good to be true: if I override the main node name with an empty coordinate named `()`, then it seems like tikz gets trouble finding the position when drawing the edge. For instance, I tried to add in your example: `\node[draw](){4444};\coordinate(-b4) at (.west);`, then I add `-b4` in the list of anchors to pic, and I add in the matrix: `\ar[ru, ->, end anchor=b4]`: then I get a line that is a few cm aways from the node, and the longer is the node, the further away the line is from touching the node…

Comment: @tobiasBora I've edited the answer. Take a look at the `\pgf@process` line. Since I've set up the node's coordinate system I don't actually need to calculate a difference between points. Since a coordinate has all anchors and points at its local origin (i.e. the coordinate itself) it made no difference what anchor has been used. A real node has its origin not at the center but at the `text` anchor. Anyway, we don't need to know where the origin is since that's why we set up the node's coordinate system.

Comment: Thank you sooo much, it works greatly, you definitely deserve some bounty for your invaluable help ^^

Comment: (I need to wait 24h to give it to you, not sure why ^^)

Comment: Btw, I discovered one issue with tikz pic: I can't define alias on the "main sub-node" (or any subnode actually)… In case you have an idea, I created a question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679647/tikz-pic-alias-to-internal-node

Answer (score 3):

I am unsure whether `tikz-cd` is the right thing to do this, but maybe you have something special in mind.

As was already proposed in the comments, you can name coordinates and nodes inside a pic and then later refer to them by appending these names to the name of the pic. So, if you, for example, name the node with the small x `-myanchor` and the pic `mypic`, then you can refer to the node with the small x inside this pic using `mypic-myanchor`. Since it is a node, you can also refer to its anchors, for example with `mypic-myanchor.south`.

Now, the next problem is how to tell Ti*k*Z to draw an arrow to a certain coordinate that is not the one it would typically point to when using the `\arrow` (or `\ar`) macro inside a `tikzcd` environment. This can be done by styling this arrow in a way so that the to-path is replaced by another path that has the relevant coordinate (or anchor) as target.

A possible solution would be as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzset{
  groundpic/.pic={
    % Code for the ground
    \draw[line width=.4pt]
    (0,0) -- (1mm,0)
    -- +(0,1mm) -- +(0,-1mm)
    ++(.4mm,0)
    -- +(0,.7mm) -- +(0,-.7mm) node[anchor=center,scale=.5] (-myanchor) {x}
    ++(.4mm,0)
    -- +(0,.35mm) -- +(0,-.35mm)
    ;
  },
  ground/.style={
    shape=coordinate, % Otherwise the arrow will not point to the center
    append after command={
      pic[scale=2] (#1) {groundpic}
    },
  },
  custom target/.style={
    to path={
      -- (#1)
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \rar & |[ground=mypic]| & \\
  B \ar[
    ru,
    custom target=mypic-myanchor.south
  ]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Thanks to Qrrbrbirlbel, I learned that `tikz-cd` already provides an option `to` that does exactly what I tried using my own `custom target` option. So, you can also just do the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzset{
  groundpic/.pic={
    % Code for the ground
    \draw[line width=.4pt]
    (0,0) -- (1mm,0)
    -- +(0,1mm) -- +(0,-1mm)
    ++(.4mm,0)
    -- +(0,.7mm) -- +(0,-.7mm) node[anchor=center, scale=.5] (-myanchor) {x}
    ++(.4mm,0)
    -- +(0,.35mm) -- +(0,-.35mm)
    ;
  },
  ground/.style={
    shape=coordinate, % Otherwise the arrow will not point to the center
    append after command={
      pic[scale=2] (#1) {groundpic}
    },
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \rar & |[ground=mypic]| & \\
  B \ar[
    ru,
    to=mypic-myanchor.south
  ]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: TikZ-CD has `to = mypic-myanchor.south` without having to adjust the `to path`. So, `\ar[ru, bend right, to=mypic-myanchor]` is still possible.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Oh, I did not know this! Then, it is even easier to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: Did you get the `name=` for `pic` references to work? I ask because it was broken. I'd be interested if you've got a workaround or fixed version - or maybe this is `tikz-cd` specific?

Comment: @cfr Not sure what you mean, but if I replace `pic[scale=2] (#1) {groundpic}` by `pic[scale=2, name=#1] {groundpic}` in both examples, it seems to work fine with a current TeX distribution.

Comment: The issue is (or was?) if you tried to use something like `<name>-<something>` after defining the coordinate `-<something>` in the `pic`. This worked in the `pic` with just `-<something>` but later references to `<name>-<something>` failed. In particular, the example of this from the manual failed. The prefix- system was (is?) broken. But I should just try it out since you don't know what I'm talking about ;).

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I think your problem comes from the fact that `end anchor` takes as argument only a coordinate defined by the corresponding element in the diagram, i.e. the element the arrow points to.

In the figure, the black arrow starting at *B* uses `end anchor=240`, i.e. it ends to the point on the border of the top right element defined by the angle 240 with respect to the *Ox* axis.  The red arrow is a normal one.

**Remark** I slightly redefined your `pic` object; I think, in case you want to use it in a diagram, it is better to define it using relative length units.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  pics/ground pic/.style={%
    code={%
      \draw
      (0, 0) -- +(0, 1.5ex) -- +(0,-1.5ex)
      ++(.5ex, 0) -- +(0, 1ex) -- +(0, -1ex)
      node[anchor=center, scale=.5, outer sep=2ex] (-g) {x}
      ++(.5ex, 0) -- +(0, .65ex) -- +(0, -.65ex);
      \draw (0, 0) -- (-1ex, 0);
    }
  },
  ground/.style={%
    outer xsep=.3ex, outer ysep=1ex, 
    insert path={%
      pic[yshift=.5ex] {ground pic}
    }
  }  
}

\begin{tikzcd}
  A \arrow[r] & |[ground]|\phantom{A} \\
  B \arrow[ru, end anchor=240]
  \arrow[ru, red]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer… sadly I need more precision than a manually tunes anchor, first because I might want to go inside the node, and also because I'm designing a library to automatically do this nasty computations… and most of the (dirty) code I have so far really relies on custom anchors.

Comment: Well, I guess that in that case `tikzcd` is not the right choice; you would need more liberty in using nodes embedded into `pic` elements.  To achieve this you might need `tikz` instead.