# Tikz pic: alias to internal node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd, tikz-pic

How could I define an alias to a node inside a Ti*k*Z pic?

On this MWE, the black line is the line I'd like to obtain (using alias instead of relative positioning), while the red one is the best I can get:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{
  groundpic/.pic={
    % the () makes sure the node "replaces" the parent node (this way, \rar points to this node)
    \node[draw,alias=internalB](){Some text};
    % \tikzset{add anchor to pic'/.list={t1, b1, t2, b2, t3, b3}}
  },
  ground/.style={
    shape=coordinate, yshift=axis_height,
    append after command={
      pic[scale=2,at=(\tikzlastnode),name=\tikzlastnode,alias=semiInternalB]{groundpic}
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  |[alias=myA]| A \rar & |[ground, alias=myB]|
  % Works, but is pointing to the center of the shape, while I would like it to point to the inner nodes itself. 
  \ar[from=myA, to=myB, red]
  % % Fails:
  %\ar[from=myA, to=internalB, green]
  % % Fails:
  %\ar[from=myA, to=semiInternalB, green]  
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

This question is a follow up of: [Tikz pic: use internal nodes as anchor name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/676017/tikz-pic-use-internal-nodes-as-anchor-name/676090?noredirect=1#comment1686282_676090)

**EDIT**: seems like:

```
append after command={\pgfextra{\pgfnodealias{bidule}{\tikzlastnode}}}
```

does a much better job than `alias=…`, no idea why… any idea what's going wrong with alias?

**EDIT** To give a full example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{
  groundpic/.pic={
    % the () makes sure the node "replaces" the parent node (this way, \rar points to this node)
    \node[draw,alias=internalB](){Some text};
    % \tikzset{add anchor to pic'/.list={t1, b1, t2, b2, t3, b3}}
  },
  ground/.style={
    shape=coordinate, yshift=axis_height,
    append after command={
      pic[scale=2,at=(\tikzlastnode),name=\tikzlastnode,append after command={\pgfextra{\pgfnodealias{bidule}{\tikzlastnode}}}]{groundpic}
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  |[alias=myA]| A & |[ground]|
  % Works, but is pointing to the center of the shape, while I would like it to point to the inner nodes itself. 
  \ar[from=myA, to=bidule, red]
  % % Fails:
  %\ar[from=myA, to=internalB, green]
  % % Fails:
  %\ar[from=myA, to=semiInternalB, green]  
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your `append after command` (after the `append after command = {pic …}` I'm assuming) will get executed after the pic and now `\tikzlastnode` is the name of the pic's internal node which will make a copy of that node (including all the fake anchors added via `add anchor to pic'`). The coordinate is long forgotten.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks a lot for your help. Actually, I'm doing the `append after command` inside the pic specification (I added an example above, the syntax might feel weird, but I have wrapper commands anyway that make it natural to put it here). So I guess `\tikzlastnode` will not change much? Or should I create an alias to copy it somehow for more security? I'm not sure to understand your comment on copying the node's content. What is supposed to copy the node?

Comment: That's probably no difference because both version (mine as an option to the coordinate or yours as an option to the pic) will execute the aliasing after the pic and will reference the node that's named `()`. Not copying the node's *content* but copying the *node* itself including all its internal macros.

Comment: An alias will just create a second node on the TeX level which are just five global macros: 1. shape, 2. saved anchors, 3. coordinate system, 4. picture ID, 5. saved macros. The fifth is the one that's used by `add anchor to node` and thus you will need to alias those nodes after the extra anchors have been added. The alias isn't synced to the original.

Comment: Actually, I want to add the alias to `()` so that's actually what I'm aiming at. Oh, I thought that alias was a very stupid primitive that was just saying `if you want to use this node… well go to see that other node`, I was not thinking it was producing a whole new copy, it's much clearer now. If I do create the alias last (I should have a way to do so), is the copying mostly an efficiency issue or does it has other nasty effects?

Comment: Also I guess I have no other method to know the original name of the alias than manually remembering that link when creating the alias?

Comment: Also, wouldn't a "light alias" that only does `\def…` instead of `\let` work without the above issues? Or is it important for LaTeX that alias actually copy the macros with let?

Comment: We could try to create a macro `\pgfnodelink{other name}{original}` that works similar to an alias but actually just points to `original`. But when you then create a new node named `original` that pointer points to the new node and the old one is lost unless an alias was made from the original or an alias of it.

Comment: Technically this is not so much of an issue as `original` shouldn't change of name (since they contain the position in the matrix in their name anyway). Also, regarding you comment on `add anchor to node`, since this is run while defining the pic, isn't `append after command` guaranteed to be run after setting up the anchors?

Comment: I'm running late now. It seemy my answer doesn't really give you the solution you've worked out yourself now but hopefully it makes it clearer why the aliasing is best done after everything has been done.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much for all you help. It's really, really, helpful, and much clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an overwhelming situation you have here.
Let's break it down:

- The macro `\tikzlastnode` simply holds the name (not any of the aliases) of the last node (a coordinate is just another node) or pic if it has been explicitly named.

  ```
  \tikz
     \coordinate[
       name=COORDINATE,
       append after command={
         \pgfextra{\typeout{\tikzlastnode}}
         pic[
           name=PIC,
           append after command=\pgfextra{\typeout{\tikzlastnode}}]{code=}
       },
       append after command=\pgfextra{\typeout{\tikzlastnode}}];
  ```

  will put `COORDINATE` once and `PIC` twice in the logfile.
- Thus, an `alias`ed coordinate will not “pass down” its alias to anything that has to do with `\tikzlastnode` (label, pin, append/prefix after commands).
- An alias on a `pic` doesn't do anything.
  A pic isn't an object, its content can however inherit its name.
- A node inside a pic with an `alias` will have the same pic name prefixed as the normal name.
- Aliasing a node will make a copy of the node on the TeX level. These copies are now independent.

  ```
  \node[alias=A-copy](A){};
  \node              (A){};
  ```

  will leave two nodes: `A-copy` (the first one)  and `A` (the second one).

  On the TeX level, a node exists of five macros for

  1. the shape,
  2. the saved anchors,
  3. the node's local coordinate system (location, rotation, scaling, shearing),
  4. the picture ID (used for drawing between pictures) and
  5. the saved macros which contains the rest: ad-hoc anchors, the extra anchors I've added in my linked answer.
- The `add anchor to node` keys from my linked answer will only be added to one of the copies: the one that has been specified via its name.

  Aliasing such a node needs to be done after the extra anchors have been added. Whether that's directly inside the pic or after the pic should be of no concern.
- I've added an untested `\pgfnodelink` macro as well as needed TikZ key `alias link` to the code. I haven't tested it yet. (Just naming it `link` seemed dangerous as it might be a popular key name used for edges.)

That means:

- The first arrow to `myB` just points to the coordinate. That's the one that gets aliased to `myB`, nothing else.
- Your first failed arrow needs

  ```
  \ar[from=myA, to=tikz@f@1-1-2internalB, green]
  ```

  where `tikz@f@1` is the internal name given to the matrix and 1 is the row and 2 is the column since it uses the same prefix/suffix setup as for the name itself and thus uses the pic's name as a prefix.
- `alias = semiInternalB` does nothing here.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{
  groundpic/.pic={
    % the () makes sure the node "replaces" the parent node (this way, \rar points to this node)
    \node[draw,alias=internalB](){Some text};
    % \tikzset{add anchor to pic'/.list={t1, b1, t2, b2, t3, b3}}
  },
  ground/.style={
    shape=coordinate, yshift=axis_height,
    append after command={
      pic[scale=2,at=(\tikzlastnode),name=\tikzlastnode,alias=semiInternalB]{groundpic}
    }
  },
}
\makeatletter
% A primitive test whether a node name exists
% (somewhere not necessarily inside the current TikZ picture)
\newcommand*\tikznodeexistTF[3]{\pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}}

% add link/pointer
\def\pgfutil@namedefname#1#2{% untested
  \expandafter\gdef\csname#1\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}}
\def\pgfnodelink#1#2{% untested
  \pgfutil@namedefname{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{pgf@sh@ns@#2}%
  \pgfutil@namedefname{pgf@sh@np@#1}{pgf@sh@np@#2}%
  \pgfutil@namedefname{pgf@sh@nt@#1}{pgf@sh@nt@#2}%
  \pgfutil@namedefname{pgf@sh@pi@#1}{pgf@sh@pi@#2}%
  \pgfutil@namedefname{pgf@sh@ma@#1}{pgf@sh@ma@#2}}
\tikzset{alias link/.code={%
  \tikz@fig@mustbenamed
  \begingroup
    \toks0=\expandafter{\tikz@alias}%
    \edef\pgf@temp{\noexpand\pgfnodelink{\tikz@pp@name{#1}}{\noexpand\tikz@fig@name}}%
    \toks1=\expandafter{\pgf@temp}%
    \xdef\pgf@marshal{\noexpand\def\noexpand\tikz@alias{\the\toks0 \the\toks1 }}%
  \endgroup
  \pgf@marshal}}%
\makeatother

% Log entries for creating/aliasing/linking
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\pgfmultipartnode}{\typeout{Creating node #3 in \pgfpictureid}}{}{\PatchFailed}
\pretocmd{\pgfnodealias}    {\typeout{Aliasing #2 -> #1}}                {}{\PatchFailed}
\pretocmd{\pgfnodelink}     {\typeout{Linking #2 -> #1}}                 {}{\PatchFailed}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  |[alias=myA]| A \rar & |[ground, alias=myB]|
  % Works, but is pointing to the center of the shape, while I would like it to point to the inner nodes itself. 
  \ar[from=myA, to=myB, red]
  % % Fails:
  \ar[from=myA, to=tikz@f@1-1-2internalB, green]
  % % Fails:
%  \ar[from=myA, to=semiInternal, green]  
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[
  alias=C',
  append after command={
    pic[alias=P'](P){
      code={
        \node[draw, alias=N'](){};
      }
    }
  }] (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\foreach \nodename in {C, C', P, P', PN', P'N'}{
  \par               % y  y   y  n   y    n
  The node name \texttt{\nodename}
  \tikznodeexistTF{\nodename}{exists}{doesn't exist}.
}

\tikz
  \coordinate[
    name=COORDINATE,
    append after command={
      \pgfextra{\typeout{\tikzlastnode}}
      pic[
        name=PIC,
        append after command=\pgfextra{\typeout{\tikzlastnode}}]{code=}},
    append after command=\pgfextra{\typeout{\tikzlastnode}}];
\end{document}
```