# Grouping multiple elements into a single TikZ shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

I want to create a `switch` multipart shape by grouping several elements while preserving the anchors `(sw)`, `(sw1)`, `(sw2)`, and `(sw3)`, such that I can insert it with the `\node` command and connect to it other nodes by referring to its sub-anchors.

In short, all I'd like to do is group & anchor as one does in Microsoft Visio.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=6pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,positioning,calc,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  neuron/.style = {circle, very thick, minimum size=7.5mm, inner sep=0, outer sep=0, draw},
  cost/.style={rectangle, minimum size=7.5mm, inner sep=0, outer sep=0},
  switch/.style={cost, draw=gray, opacity=.1, densely dashed, node contents={}},
  contact/.style={neuron, node contents={}, minimum size=2mm},
  location/.style={circle, inner sep=0, outer sep=0, node contents={}, minimum size=3pt, fill},
  node distance=7.5mm,
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % Place nodes
    \node (n1) [neuron] {\(n_1\)};
    \node (n2) [neuron, right=of n1] {\(n_2\)};
    % Switch elements ------------------------------------------------
    \node at ($ (n1)!.5!(n2) + (0,1)$) (sw) [switch];
    \node at (sw.west) (sw1) [contact, anchor=west];
    \node at (sw.east) (sw2) [contact, anchor=east];
    \draw [very thick, line cap=round]
      ($(sw1.south)!.5!(sw2.south)$) -- ++(0,2mm)
      node (sw3) [location];
    \def\r{2.3mm}\def\delta{90}
    \draw [{Latex[length=2pt]}-{Latex[length=2pt]}, gray]
      ($(-90-\delta/2:\r)+(sw3)$)
      arc [radius=\r, start angle=-90-\delta/2, delta angle=\delta];
    % ----------------------------------------------------------------
    \node at ($(sw) + (0,1)$) (n3) [neuron] {\(n_3\)};
    % Connect nodes
    \graph[use existing nodes] {
      n1 ->[to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}] sw1;
      n2 ->[to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}] sw2;
      sw3 -> n3;
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe create a `\pic` or add a `path picture` to a node?

Comment: A `pic` would be the easiest, you can add fake anchors to it (by naming coordinates inside it) or [hack real ones in](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/576909). Fake ones are usually enough, if you don't depend on the `.` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `\pic`, but this approach would not directly be compatible with using a `\graph` for connecting things:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc, arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    neuron/.style={
        circle, very thick, minimum size=7.5mm, inner sep=0, outer sep=0, draw
    },
    cost/.style={
        rectangle, minimum size=7.5mm, inner sep=0, outer sep=0
    },
    switch/.style={
        cost, draw=gray, opacity=.1, densely dashed, node contents={},
    },
    switch pic/radius/.initial=2.3mm,
    switch pic/delta angle/.initial=90,
    pics/switch pic/.style={
        code={
            \tikzset{switch pic/.cd, #1}
            \node (-center) [switch];
            \node at (-center.west) (-west) [contact, anchor=west];
            \node at (-center.east) (-east) [contact, anchor=east];
            \draw[very thick, line cap=round]
                ($(-west.south)!.5!(-east.south)$) -- ++(0,2mm)
                node (-location) [location];
            \draw[{Latex[length=2pt]}-{Latex[length=2pt]}, gray]
                ($(-90-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/switch pic/delta angle}/2:
                \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/switch pic/radius})+(-location)$)
                arc[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/switch pic/radius}, 
                start angle=-90-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/switch pic/delta angle}/2, 
                delta angle=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/switch pic/delta angle}];
        }
    },
    contact/.style={
        neuron, node contents={}, minimum size=2mm
    },
    location/.style={
        circle, inner sep=0, outer sep=0, node contents={}, minimum size=3pt, fill
    },
    node distance=7.5mm,
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % Place nodes
    \node (n1) [neuron] {\(n_1\)};
    \node (n2) [neuron, right=of n1] {\(n_2\)};
    % Switch elements ------------------------------------------------
    \pic at ($(n1)!.5!(n2) + (0,1)$) (sw) {switch pic={radius=2.3mm, delta angle=90}};
    % ----------------------------------------------------------------
    \node at ($(sw-center) + (0,1)$) (n3) [neuron] {\(n_3\)};
    % Connect nodes
    \draw[->] (n1) |- (sw-west);
    \draw[->] (n2) |- (sw-east);
    \draw[->] (sw-location) -- (n3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You could also use a `path picture`, which would allow you to use a `\graph`, but requires some other adjustments:

- You'd need to enlarge the node that is assigned the `path picture` a bit, because the contents would be clipped away otherwise. The line width of the very thick circles needs to be taken into account here.
- I would suggest that you add an argument to the `switch` style, so that you can later identify the right nodes if you use this style multiple times.

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, positioning, calc, arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    neuron/.style={
        circle, very thick, minimum size=7.5mm, inner sep=0, outer sep=0, draw
    },
    cost/.style={
        rectangle, minimum size=7.5mm, inner sep=0, outer sep=0
    },
    switch radius/.initial=2.3mm,
    switch delta angle/.initial=90,
    switch/.style={
        minimum size={7.5mm+1.2pt}, 
        path picture={
            \node at (path picture bounding box.center) 
                (switch center #1) [cost, draw=gray, opacity=.1, densely dashed] {};
            \node at (switch center #1.west) 
                (switch west #1) [contact, anchor=west];
            \node at (switch center #1.east) 
                (switch east #1) [contact, anchor=east];
            \draw[very thick, line cap=round]
                ($(switch west #1.south)!.5!(switch east #1.south)$) -- ++(0,2mm)
                node (switch location #1) [location];
            \draw[{Latex[length=2pt]}-{Latex[length=2pt]}, gray]
                ($(-90-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/switch delta angle}/2:
                \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/switch radius})+(switch location #1)$)
                arc[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/switch radius}, 
                start angle=-90-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/switch delta angle}/2, 
                delta angle=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/switch delta angle}];
        }, 
        node contents={}
    },
    contact/.style={
        neuron, node contents={}, minimum size=2mm
    },
    location/.style={
        circle, inner sep=0, outer sep=0, node contents={}, minimum size=3pt, fill
    },
    node distance=7.5mm,
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % Place nodes
    \node (n1) [neuron] {\(n_1\)};
    \node (n2) [neuron, right=of n1] {\(n_2\)};
    % Switch elements ------------------------------------------------
    \node at ($(n1)!.5!(n2) + (0,1)$) (sw) [switch={1}];
    % ----------------------------------------------------------------
    \node at ($(sw) + (0,1)$) (n3) [neuron] {\(n_3\)};
    % Connect nodes
    \graph[use existing nodes] {
      n1 -> [to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}] switch west 1;
      n2 -> [to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}] switch east 1;
      switch location 1 -> n3;
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was a bit amazed that you're actually able to refer to nodes inside the `path picture`. I am not sure whether this is a bug or a feature actually ...

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed! Question: why won't we could create an actual node shape with a square and additional drawing instructions specified with `append after command={\pgfextra{}}`? That would let me use the `\graph` command and have no clipping, if I understand it correctly.

Comment: @Atcold Well, maybe you could also get this working using `append after command`, but this is eventually not much different from `path picture`.  The typical way to create such "sub-pictures" are `\pic`s which is why I came up with such a solution. Creating an actual shape (including everything) would also be possible actually (but a bit more complicated).