# Latex TIKZ - Draw YAWL Workflow Task

Tags: tikz-pgf, workflow

i would like to create a YAWL pattern for my thesis. The pattern consists of tasks, as shown in the picture below, with my final model looking like the drawn graph (a simplified version of it).

[image: YAWL pattern elements]

[image: Desired workflow model]

I really like the design of the following diagram https://texample.net/tikz/examples/model-physics/. My problem is that I really do not understand how to start the development of my own model (even after extensive research), while simultaneously being overwhelmed by the possibilities of f.e. \usetikzlibrary, newcommand, nodes in a node, or even tikzpicture in tikzspicture - I no longer have an overview of potential solutions.

- How can I define a flexible TIKZ task definition that I can use throughout the workflow model?
- Is there a best practice for designing such a workflow model in general?

I would be very grateful for a brief explanation from you or just a link that answers my questions (docs and other tutorials I've found have only helped me to a limited extent for my specific case)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tasks:

1. The look of the nodes.
2. The placing of the nodes.
3. Connecting the nodes.

### 1. Look of the nodes

Here's a vanilla TikZ approach.

All those symbols are `circle` or `rectangle` shapes that get something extra drawn via `label` (which places another node in relation to the node where we use it)  and `append after command` (which allow us to use `\tikzlastnode` to refer to the last placed node's name).

- In the case of the Input and the Output Condition
  it's just another shape (a `label`) that get's filled.
- The Composite Task is just a `double` rectangle.
- The Multiple Tasks get an extra border drawn.
  (There is also [`copy shadow`](https://tikz.dev/library-shadows#tikz/copy:shadow).)
- The Split Tasks are again `rectangle` nodes that get drawn extra stuff.

With

- `add anchor alias to me` and
- `add anchor to me`

custom anchors are added to only that `rectangle`.

(In the `split` case these are `.in` which is just an alias for `.west` and `out 1` and `out 2`. For `join` it's just the other way around.)

The `calc` library allows us to write `($(<c1>)!<perc>!(<c2>)$)` which specifies the point thats `perc`-partly between `c1` and `c2`.

(The extra anchors use this with `\pgfpointlineattime`.)

---

This solution could be improved by using the shapes from the [`shapes.gates.logic` library](https://tikz.dev/library-circuits#pgf.shapes.gates.logic) and just removing the text (and still adding the extra stuff to it).

These shapes come with a variable number of input and output anchors (which can also be drawn inverted).

The various `circuits` libraries also provide more keys that might help in drawing these diagrams.
And then there's also the [`circuitikz` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz) (→ [circuitikz](/questions/tagged/circuitikz)) but I haven't seen any logic gates there.

### 2. Placing of nodes.

There are dozens of ways to place nodes.

I've used a `\matrix` here because it places all nodes neatly on a grid and names them `<matrix name>-<row>-<column>`.

There are other approaches with the `chains` library and the `graphs` library.

### 3. Connecting the nodes.

I'm just using a bunch of `edge` operations, the `ext.paths.ortho` library of my [`tikz-ext` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext) helps with a few orthogonal lines:

- `horizontal vertical horizontal` (= `-|-`),
- `only horizontal first` (which seems to be bugged because `.west` has to declared manually),
- `only horizontal second` and
- the `r-du` operation that uses auxilliary coordinates to draw the loop edge.

The `tikzcd` package allows one to place nodes in a matrix and specify connections without having to now where in the matrix the nodes are which can be used here similarly.

### There's more.

The `fit` and the `backgrounds` library help to draw a green rectangle behind other parts of your diagram.

### Code

```
\documentclass[border=1pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{
    matrix,           % for matrix of nodes
    shapes.geometric, % for isosceles triangle
    calc,             % for $-syntax
    ext.paths.ortho,  % for -|-
    fit,
    backgrounds,
}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  add anchor to node/.code n args={3}{%
    \edef\tikz@temp##1{%  \tikz@pp@name/\tikzlastnode needs to be expanded
      \noexpand\pgfutil@g@addto@macro\expandafter\noexpand\csname pgf@sh@ma@\tikz@pp@name{#1}\endcsname{%
        \def\expandafter\noexpand\csname pgf@anchor@\csname pgf@sh@ns@\tikz@pp@name{#1}\endcsname @#2\endcsname{##1}%
      }}\tikz@temp{#3}},
  add anchor to me/.style 2 args={append after command={
    [add anchor to node={\tikzlastnode}{#1}{#2}]}},
  add anchor alias to node/.style n args={3}{
    add anchor to node={#1}{#2}{\pgf@sh@reanchor{\csname pgf@sh@ns@\pgfreferencednodename\endcsname}{#3}}},
  add anchor alias to me/.style args={#1 for #2}{append after command={
      [add anchor alias to node={\tikzlastnode}{#1}{#2}]}}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  yawl diagram/.style={
    yawl size/.initial=1cm,
    yawl task part/.initial=.2,
    all yawl/.style={draw, minimum size=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/yawl size}},
    %% Conditions
    condition/.style={all yawl, shape=circle},
    input condition triangle/.style={
      shape=isosceles triangle, fill=black, draw=none,
      xshift=-.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/yawl size},
      minimum width=.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/yawl size},
      minimum height=.3*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/yawl size}},
    output condition square/.style={
      shape=rectangle, fill=black, draw=none,
      minimum size=.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/yawl size}},
    input condition/.style={
      condition, label={[input condition triangle]center:}},
    output condition/.style={
      condition, label={[output condition square]center:}},
    %% Tasks
    atomic task/.style={all yawl, shape=rectangle},
    composite task/.style={
      atomic task, double, double distance=1.5pt,
      outer sep=2\pgflinewidth+\pgfinnerlinewidth},
    multiple path/.style n args=3{
     append after command={
        ([xshift=##1]\tikzlastnode.north west)
        edge[##3, to path={|- ([shift={(##2,##2)}]\tikzlastnode.north east)
                          |- ([yshift=##1]\tikzlastnode.south east)}] ()}},
    multiple atomics/.style={atomic task, multiple path={2pt}{2pt}{}},
    multiple composites/.style={composite task, multiple path={4pt}{2pt}{double, double distance=1.5pt}},
    %% … that was the easy part
    %% Tasks
    task/.style={
      all yawl, minimum width=1.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/yawl size}, shape=rectangle},
    task right/.style={
      task, add anchor alias to me=in for west,
      add anchor to me={out 1}{\pgfpointlineattime{.3}{\northeast}{\csname pgf@anchor@rectangle@south east\endcsname}},
      add anchor to me={out 2}{\pgfpointlineattime{.7}{\northeast}{\csname pgf@anchor@rectangle@south east\endcsname}},
      append after command={
        ($(\tikzlastnode.north east)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/yawl task part}!(\tikzlastnode.north west)$)
        edge coordinate[midway] (@)
        ($(\tikzlastnode.south east)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/yawl task part}!(\tikzlastnode.south west)$)
        ##1}},
    task left/.style={
      task, add anchor alias to me=out for east,
      add anchor to me={in 1}{\pgfpointlineattime{.7}{\southwest}{\csname pgf@anchor@rectangle@north west\endcsname}},
      add anchor to me={in 2}{\pgfpointlineattime{.3}{\southwest}{\csname pgf@anchor@rectangle@north west\endcsname}},
      append after command={
        ($(\tikzlastnode.north west)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/yawl task part}!(\tikzlastnode.north east)$)
        edge coordinate[midway] (@)
        ($(\tikzlastnode.south west)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/yawl task part}!(\tikzlastnode.south east)$)
        ##1}},
    and split/.style={
      task right={(\tikzlastnode.north east) edge[shorten >=\pgflinewidth, shorten <=\pgflinewidth,
         to path={--(@)--(\tikzlastnode.south east)}]()}},
    xor split/.style={
      task right={(\tikzlastnode.north east-|@) edge[shorten >=\pgflinewidth, shorten <=\pgflinewidth,
         to path={--([xshift=-.5\pgflinewidth]\tikzlastnode.east)--(\tikzlastnode.south east-|@)}]()}},
    or split/.style={
      task right={%
        \pgfextra{\let\tln\tikzlastnode}
        ([yshift=-.5\pgflinewidth]$(\tikzlastnode.north east)!.5!(\tikzlastnode.north-|@)$)
        edge[line join=bevel, to path={-- coordinate[at start](@@) (@) -- ([yshift=.5\pgflinewidth]\tln.south-|@@)
                                       -- ([xshift=-.5\pgflinewidth]\tln.east) -- cycle}]()
        \pgfextra{\let\tikzlastnode\tln}}},
    and join/.style={
        task left={(\tikzlastnode.north west) edge[shorten >=\pgflinewidth, shorten <=\pgflinewidth,
           to path={--(@)--(\tikzlastnode.south west)}]()}},
      xor join/.style={
        task left={(\tikzlastnode.north east-|@) edge[shorten >=\pgflinewidth, shorten <=\pgflinewidth,
           to path={--([xshift=.5\pgflinewidth]\tikzlastnode.west)--(\tikzlastnode.south west-|@)}]()}},
      or join/.style={
        task left={%
          \pgfextra{\let\tln\tikzlastnode}
          ([yshift=-.5\pgflinewidth]$(\tikzlastnode.north west)!.5!(\tikzlastnode.north-|@)$)
          edge[line join=bevel, to path={-- coordinate[at start](@@) (@) -- ([yshift=.5\pgflinewidth]\tln.south-|@@)
                                         -- ([xshift=.5\pgflinewidth]\tln.west) -- cycle}]()
          \pgfextra{\let\tikzlastnode\tln}}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  yawl diagram,
  %
  add split/.style={
    append after command={(\tikzlastnode.in)    edge[<-] ++(left:10pt)
                          (\tikzlastnode.out 1) edge[->] ++(right:10pt)
                          (\tikzlastnode.out 2) edge[->] ++(right:10pt)}},
  add split'/.style={
    append after command={(\tikzlastnode.in 1) edge[<-] ++(left:10pt)
                          (\tikzlastnode.in 2) edge[<-] ++(left:10pt)
                          (\tikzlastnode.out)  edge[->] ++(right:10pt)}}
]

\matrix [
  matrix of nodes, row sep=2mm, column sep=2mm,
  thick,
  >=latex,
  column 2/.style={anchor=mid west},
  column 4/.style={anchor=mid west}] {
 |[condition]|        & Condition        & |[atomic task]|         & Atomic task \\
 |[input condition]|  & Input condition  & |[composite task]|      & Composite task \\
 |[output condition]| & Output condition & |[multiple atomics]|    & Multiple atomic tasks \\
                      &                  & |[multiple composites]| & Multiple composite tasks \\
 |[and split, add split]| & AND-split & |[and join, add split']| & AND-join \\
 |[xor split, add split]| & XOR-split & |[xor join, add split']| & XOR-join \\
 |[or split,  add split]| & OR-split  & |[or join,  add split']| & OR-join \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yawl diagram]
\matrix (m) [
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep=1cm,
  column sep=1cm,
  l/.style={label={[node font=\scriptsize]below:\vphantom{gV}#1}},
  mgnt/.style={fill=magenta!50}
] {
     & & & & |[composite task, l = Automation]| \\
  |[input condition]|
     & |[xor join, l = loop join]|
       & |[task, l = next step]|
         & |[xor split, l = \dots, mgnt]|
           & |[task, l = manual]|
             & |[xor join, mgnt]|
               & |[xor split, l = loop]|
                 & |[condition]| \\
};
\path[->, thick, shorten >=\pgflinewidth]
  (m-2-1)       edge[horizontal vertical horizontal] coordinate[pos=.85] (loop start) (m-2-2.in 1)
  (m-2-2)       edge (m-2-3)
  (m-2-3)       edge (m-2-4)
  (m-2-4.out 2) edge[only horizontal first] (m-2-5.west)
  (m-2-4.out 1) edge[horizontal vertical horizontal] (m-1-5)
  (m-2-5)       edge[only horizontal second] (m-2-6.in 2)
  (m-1-5)       edge[horizontal vertical horizontal] (m-2-6.in 1)
  (m-2-6)       edge (m-2-7)
  (m-2-7.out 1) edge[horizontal vertical horizontal] coordinate[pos=.15] (loop end) (m-2-8)
  (m-2-7.out 2) edge[
    udlr/du distance=2cm,
    to path={--(loop end|-\tikztostart)r-du(loop start|-\tikztotarget)--(\tikztotarget)}] (m-2-2.in 2)
;
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \node[draw,
     fill=green!33,
     fit=(m-1-5)(m-2-4)(m-2-6),
     inner ysep=.7cm,
     inner xsep=.5cm,
     yshift=-.35cm,
     label={[anchor=south]south:\textsc{Decision}}
]{};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'll add to the answer later on.

Comment: Thank you. Really just thank you. Just by defining the tasks you have already helped me more than enough :)